# Not getting value for records-lag-max for kafka consumer jmx metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, jmx, metrics, producer-consumer

I am running a java kafka stream application with JMX enabled. I am trying to fetch the consumer lags but getting **infinity** for all the consumers that application have.

I am looking the below jmx metrics:

```
kafka.consumer.type_consumer-fetch-manager-metrics.client-id_consumer-v1*.records-lag-max
```

I am not sure why it is not giving the exact value. Please let me know:

- If I am missing something here,
- OR, looking the wrong metrics,
- OR Need to do some extra configuration to get the consumer lags.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason for the issue. Actually, in the case of consumer lags, my service was retrying infinite time to connect to the database which was stooping consumers to generate the metrics, therefore, I was getting the value as infinite.

So, there was nothing wrong from JMX side, it was the use case which was causing the issue.